# How to update a bit in byte field

Tags: db2

Friends, I have an issue where there is a DB2 column of size 1 Char which is broken into 8 bits or flags and I want to update first 2 flags or bits to either 1 or 0. How do I achieve that through DB2. I can do it through programs. But I need the Db2 query to run it on Spufi. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let `TBL` be your table, `FLG` your flags CHAR(1) column and `VAL` the new byte values to add to the flag:

```
UPDATE TBL
SET FLG = CHR(BITOR(BITANDNOT(ASCII(FLG),3),BITAND(VAL,3)))
```

`BITANDNOT` preserves all bits except the lowest 2 bits
`BITAND` keeps only the lower 2 bits of `VAL`
`BITOR` combines the two values into the result
`CHR` and `ASCII` convert the value back and forth